# how to run subprogram from another file in fortran using vscode

Tags: windows, visual-studio, build, fortran, intel-fortran

I have 2 Fortran source files, the function as the subprogram and the main code for running the program, how can I call the function in the main program?

if using gfortran in Linux we can use

```
gfortran mainprogram.f90 subprogram.f90
```

If I use Microsoft Visual Studio how can I write the code?

Comment: \If the code you have works in gfortran, it is probably reasonably correct Fortran (maybe with some bugs). You thefore should not ask how to write the code. You already have the code. You should write how to compile your project in your IDE. BTW, you certainly can use similar commands you use in Linux also in MS Windows. The intel compilers `ifort` and `ifx` also work in the command line. Just try `ifort mainprogram.f90 subprogram.f90` after initializing the environment following your manual.

Comment: I deleted the Python `import` mention, it really makes little sense. Of course you can, and you should, learn how to write modules and how to `use` them, but that is a completely different issue. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: And BTW, you in your title you mentions VS Code and in the question body you mention MS Visual Studio. These are two completely different products. Which of them do you actually mean?

Comment: the python import is just an example how to call a function from another file

Comment: Also, are you using Visual Studio on Windows or Visual Studio Code on Windows/Linux?

Comment: i use visual studio on windows